# Can a Flex Air Window (NativeWindow) be modal? how?

Tags: apache-flex, air, flex4

Can a Flax Air Window (NativeWindow) be modal? how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to expand on your use case.

If you want it to be modal, do you want to shut down the entire operating system until this window is handled by the user?  I doubt that is possible.  Do OSes support that in any way? (Other than when crashing).

If you want to prevent your app from being used while this window is up, don't use NativeWindow use a component with the PopUpManager.  It has a modal property when creating the popup.

Comment: i will open a settings window of my application in a "system" window, and prevent clicking in the application...

Comment: I wouldn't use Native Window for that.  NativeWindow opens up a new Operating System window. Instead create your own "setting" component and open that using the PopUpManager.  Take a look at MS Word, or your browser. All the setting Windows are contained within the app.

Comment: ok, i will change the windows to components, but in other lenguajes, this is posible. Tanks for the help

Comment: Which languages?  Got any samples?  Any test programs that I can run?

Comment: In java swing, we can make slave windows.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible way would have been to do something like

```
private function _onActivate(__e:Event):void
{
    if ( _settingsWindow )
    {
        __e.preventDefault();
        _settingsWindow.activate()
    }
}
```

and when you open up your settings window, set everything on the "mainapplications" stage to `mouseEnabled = false; mouseChildren = false;` and listen for the settingswindow close event to reactivate the mouse enabled and set `_settingsWindow` to null and mainapplications window to activate again (just to make sure)